# Вёрстка спрайтами

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Вывожу картинку из спрайта, код такой:

http://jsfiddle.net/bn6np/

```css
.menu_left_icons_imgn {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Nei574m.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.menu_left_icons_img_active {
    background: url('../images/menu_left_icons_active.png?11');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_new_task {
    background-position: 0px 0px !important;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_all_task {
    background-position: 0px -26px !important;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_my_tasks {
    background-position: 0px -49px !important;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_complaints {
    background-position: 0px -73px !important;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_blacklist {
    background-position: 0px -96px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_left_icons_imgn menu_left_icons_img_blacklist"></div>
```

Проблема в том, что если в Chrome нажать Ctrl+, т.е увеличить масштаб страницы, то иконка будто спадает вниз, обрезается и получается некрасиво. Скрин ниже:

[image]

Как это исправить? + ещё качество иконок портится ><

Comment: Описанный эффект наблюдается только при масштабе 110 процентов, масштабирование без потерь не получится

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, вообще чтоли это неисправимо? Может я просто не так верстаю? Потому что не на всех иконках наблюдается такой эффект.

Comment: Делайте блок чуть больше на пару пикселей и собственно спрайты размечайте с большим пространством друг от друга тогда эти косяки масштабирования нивелируются свободным пространством. P.S> Если к вашему примеру добавить padding: 2px; то всё отлично смотриться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Грязный [хак](http://jsfiddle.net/mmWY3/1/).

```css
.menu_left_icons_imgn {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Nei574m.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 16.1px;
    height: 16.1px;
    opacity: 1;
}
.menu_left_icons_img_active {
    background: url('../images/menu_left_icons_active.png?11');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_new_task {
    background-position: 0px 0px !important;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_all_task {
    background-position: 0px -26px !important;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_my_tasks {
    background-position: 0px -49px !important;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_complaints {
    background-position: 0px -73px !important;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.menu_left_icons_imgn.menu_left_icons_img_blacklist {
    background-position: 0px -96px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_left_icons_imgn menu_left_icons_img_blacklist"></div>
```